# Opening multiple documents

Tags: ipad

I am using iPad 3. I want to open multiple pdf documents from different locations one after another. I found this feature in one of friends iPad where all pdf files were displayed at the top of the screen and could be opened by clicking on it (one at a time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a document reader. When it ask to choose your files, you can click "all my files", where the files can be sort by type. Then choose all the files you want to open.